# SendGrid being blocked by Yahoo Mail server

Tags: azure, sendgrid, webmail, yahoo-mail

As of a few weeks ago, I noticed that I am unable to receive emails from my domain account. My application is deployed to the azure server and it uses SendGrid to send emails and this happens from my application. For example my application is  'myapplication.com' and the azure sendgrid configuration for the mail server is set up to use 'Jake@myapplication.com' but when I send and email to my yahoo account, let say to reset my password. The email never makes it, not even going to spam. I remember reading something like this a few weeks back http://sendgrid.com/blog/update-yahoos-dmarc-policy "Yahoo New Policy" but I don't see how that would effect me since my from account is not a yahoo account. If there is no fix for this, what is an alternative email setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before considering an alternate email setup, contact SendGrid through [support.sendgrid.com](http://support.sendgrid.com), it's possible that Yahoo is wrongly blocking your email. If this is the case SendGrid will advocate for you and work to get it unblocked.

**Disclaimer**: I am a SendGrid Employee

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at the sendgrid dashboard and search for that email. You will be able to see exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that Sendgrid IP pool is being deferred by yahoo. I am not sure what Sendgrid is planing to do to rectify this issue as it is impacting their clients who uses shared pool service

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled on this issue. And it's not only Yahoo blocking sendgrid emails. They rather complaining about the senders ip address "Send Grid" rather than senders email address.  :-(